# how to detect mouse click after using jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I want to detect when i leave mouse click. I used mouseup() event for this but it is not working .

```
    $('#price-slider').mouseup(function(){
alert('hello');
});
```

How to detect it?

Comment: please show your markup.

Comment: should work with mouseup see here > https://jsfiddle.net/mz9ua7mu/

Comment: but when i click ...button is still pressed and i remove cursor from data then it will not display alert. @Mihai T

Comment: so you want even if you keep the click on , but go with cursor outside the element, the alert to show ?

Comment: Yes exactly.. @MihaiT

Comment: That isn't how mouseup works. The mouse UP action will apply to the element over which it occurs. If you want to capture the mouseup on the entire page, put the event on the body tag like $('body').mouseup(...

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 2 different events in the same time

1. mouseup 2. mouseleave

see snippet below

```js
 $('#price-slider').on("mouseup mouseleave",function(){
alert('hello');
});
```

```css
#price-slide {
 display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-slider">
click
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the desired behavior. Just mousing over and away from the element fires the event now.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to detect a click, don't use .mouseup, but .click.

```
$('#price-slider').click(function () {
    alert('Hello');
})
```

or

```
$('#price-slider').on('click', function () {
    alert('Hello');
})
```

See also https://api.jquery.com/click/